# How to use python-logstash on Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use python-logstash for ElasticSearch (localy).

I'm making this according to the [README](https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash) file.

My problem is that the statistics are not logged.

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    codec => json
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

**Django settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'logstash': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logstash.LogstashHandler',
            'host': 'localhost',
            'port': 5959,
            'version': 1,
            'message_type': 'logstash',
            'fqdn': False,
            'tags': ['catalog'],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['logstash'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

**Ports**

```
Elasticsearch: 9200 and 9300
Logstash: 5000
Kibana: 5601
```